# how to split a string using c#

Tags: c#, string

I am working on a project and i want to split a string like below

```
DEV~Hi there is Sunday Tommorrow=1
```

I want to split this string as I want only text which is between the tilde(~) sign and equal sign(=).  I also don't need ~ and = sign.

I have tried following code but not able to know how to split the string with tilde

```
obj.Code.Trim().Split('=')[1].Trim()
```

With the above code I can only split the string from = to sign but I want to remove the ~ sign and text on the left hand side also.

Can anyone suggest the solution?

Comment: That's not splitting. You are trying to match a specific pattern. You need a regular expression for this

Comment: Well, you _can_ use Regex, but there would be also solutions without.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your text would have exactly one tilde and equal sign, you may try the following string split:

```cs
string input = "DEV~Hi there is Sunday Tommorrow=1";
var match = Regex.Split(input, @"[~=]")[1];
Console.WriteLine(match);  // Hi there is Sunday Tommorrow
```

Another approach, perhaps a bit more robust, would be to use a regex replacement:

```cs
string input = "DEV~Hi there is Sunday Tommorrow=1";
string match = Regex.Replace(input, @"^.*~(.*)=.*$", "$1");
Console.WriteLine(match);  // Hi there is Sunday Tommorrow
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to match a specific pattern. You need a regular expression for this. The expression `~.*=` will match everything between `~` and `=`, including the characters:

```
~Hi there is Sunday Tommorrow=
```

To avoid capturing these characters you can use `(?<=~).*(?==)`. The call `Regex.Match(myString,"(?<=~).*(?==)")` will catch just the part between the markers :

```
var match=Regex.Match(myString,"(?<=~).*(?==)");
Console.WriteLine(match);
-------------------------------
Hi there is Sunday Tommorrow
```

These are called [look-around assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). The first one, `(?<=~)` says that the match is precededed by `~` but the marker isn't included. The second one, `(?==)` says that the match is followed by `=` but again, the marker isn't included.

Another possibility is to use a group to capture the part(s) you want by using parentheses:

```
var m=Regex.Match(s,"~(.*)=");  
Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1]);
---------------------------------
Hi there is Sunday Tommorrow
```

You can use more than one group in a pattern

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to do this is using RegEx, But a smiple soloution for this case:

```
obj.Code.Trim().Split('~')[1].Split('=')[0].Trim()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code:

```
obj.Code.Trim().Split('=')[0].Trim().Split('~')[1]
```